# Plotting functions given by huge summations

Tags: plotting

I have to plot some functions of one variable. The problem is that these functions are given by very huge summations of some sine and cosine functions and, as a result, I easily exceed the memory. I was wondering if you have some suggestions in order to reduce the memory used by this kind of plotting.

Here is an example of code

```
m = RandomVariate[GaussianOrthogonalMatrixDistribution[1/60, 65000]];
dataRMT = Eigenvalues[m // N];

SFFRMT[t_] = Total[Exp[-(I t) dataRMT]] Total[Exp[(I t) dataRMT]];

M = 300;
Table[(m = 
RandomVariate[GaussianOrthogonalMatrixDistribution[1/60, 65000]];
   dataRMT = Eigenvalues[m // N];
   SFFRMT[t_] = 
SFFRMT[t] + 
 Total[Exp[-(I t) dataRMT]] Total[Exp[(I t) dataRMT]];), {i, 1, 
   M}];

LogLogPlot[Evaluate[SFFRMT[T]], {T, 0.1, 10^8}]
```

Thank you.

Cheers

Comment: Can you give us an example of such a function? Without it it's hard to know what specifically will help your case.

Comment: yes. A typical example takes a form like Sum[Sum[Exp[I * Subscript[a, ij]*t], {i, 1, 65000}], {j, 1, 200}]

Comment: That's not a function other people can plot. If you don't give an example of something other people can easily feed into `Plot[]`, then you won't be able to get much help.

Comment: You are right. Let me simplify the thing: I can create a small piece of code that realizes an example and post it

Comment: You problem is the matrix `m`: It's a $65000 \times 65000$ matrix and it will need about `65000^2 8/2^30 // N` GB of memory to store it (approximately 32 GB). And then you compute its eigenvalues with an algorithm of complexity $\operatorname{O}(n^3)$. No wonder that it's slow...

Comment: So, the plotting is not the major problem here. It is forming `SFFRMT`.

Comment: Note that you perform also quite a lot symbolic computations by adding more and more symbolic expressions to `SFFRMT[t]`. That's also not very efficient. Sorry, apart from that, I have no helpful comments. I use to ask people if they _really_ need all the eigenvalues when I see them having performance problems...

Comment: Thank you for the comment. Yes, unfortunately I need all the eigenvalues.